# Cumulative total errors

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Hello I have formula that is indeed working, but only when I Select File > Options > Enable Interative Calculation.

I have a column that has percentages

[image: Image from my spreadsheet]

In the column to the right (Column H) I have the following formula in the last row (Row 124) of that column:

`=IF(OR(H124>=100%,H124<=-100%),$G124,$G124+H123)`

My goal was to be cumulatively adding the previous day's percentage (in this case cell H123) to the present day's percentage (cell $G124) as long as that sum is not equal to or greater than 100% or less than or equal to -100%). If that 100% or -100% has occurred, I would like to start the count over with the cell value in $G124.

I kept getting a Circular Reference Error, then read somewhere that I could go to File > Options > Enable Iterative Calculation to help resolve that Error. I would rather not do this because it doesn't positively effect the whole sheet properly and I would rather just use the right formula so that I'm not using one that triggers a Circular Reference error. Any suggestions on what formula would allow me to be successful?

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that a cell can't refer to itself (except when iterative calculation is enabled), and you are trying to refer to the value of cell H124 when calculating the value of cell H124, which Excel refers to as a "circular" calculation.

There are a few ways to resolve this, but the two most straightforward would be:

---

**Option 1:**

Use a "helper" column. Pull out your if-true formula, and put that in column I. E.g, cell I124 would be `=$G124+H123`

Then rather than performing your test on the values in column H, perform it on the values in column I. E.g., cell H124 would be `=IF(OR(I124>=100%,I124<=-100%),$G124,$I124)`

You'll note that column H and I will be the same whenever the cumulative percentage is in range, and will differ whenever the cumulative percentage is out of range. Since column I refers to earlier values in column H rather than earlier values in its own column, it will carry forward the modifications that happen in column H.

---

**Option 2:**

No additional columns, but you need a more complex conditional. You can't rely on the outcome of $H124 for your conditional, so instead you need to build the underlying calculation into the conditional itself.

E.g., cell H124 would be `=IF(OR(($G124+H123)>=100%,($G124+H123)<=-100%),$G124,$G124+H123)`

---

I'm partial to option 1, because it's easier to see what's going on and easier to maintain, but adding the extra column might not fit for some reason, in which case option 2 is perfectly good.